# epub_view package display nothing

Tags: flutter, dart, epub

I am building a flutter app that needs to display an epub file fetch online, so I turn to the epub_view package since it's the most up-to-date, but when I follow the example, the screen show nothing but the title, here's the code

```
import 'package:epub_view/epub_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:internet_file/internet_file.dart';

class ReadEpubScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String episodeKey;
  final String episodeTitle;

  const ReadEpubScreen(
      {Key? key, required this.episodeKey, required this.episodeTitle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReadEpubScreen> createState() => _ReadEpubScreenState();
}

class _ReadEpubScreenState extends State<ReadEpubScreen> {
  late EpubController _epubController;

  Future fetchEpisode() async {
    var doc = await InternetFile.get(episodeKey);
    _epubController = EpubController(document: EpubDocument.openData(doc));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _epubController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchEpisode(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: EpubViewActualChapter(
                  controller: _epubController,
                  builder: (chapterValue) => Text(
                    chapterValue?.chapter?.Title?.replaceAll('\n', '').trim() ??
                        '',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.save_alt),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () => _showCurrentEpubCfi(context),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              drawer: Drawer(
                child: EpubViewTableOfContents(controller: _epubController),
              ),
              body: EpubView(
                builders: EpubViewBuilders<DefaultBuilderOptions>(
                  options: const DefaultBuilderOptions(),
                  chapterDividerBuilder: (_) => const Divider(),
                ),
                controller: _epubController,
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  snapshot.error.toString(),
                ),
              ],
            );
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        });
  }

  void _showCurrentEpubCfi(context) {
    final cfi = _epubController.generateEpubCfi();

    if (cfi != null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(cfi),
          action: SnackBarAction(
            label: 'GO',
            onPressed: () {
              _epubController.gotoEpubCfi(cfi);
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The episodeKey is the epub url, here's the output i get
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8g0G.png). As you can see, the title is loaded, which means the data is successfully fetched. But somehow, all of the content is missing. Really appreciated it if someone could help me out on this.

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: No, i just resort to using Bibi epub reader and a web view, the package seems faulty.

Comment: Some pieces of ePub are not rendered properly, for example tables are not rendered at all (nor their content) at least for version 3.0.0. More here: https://github.com/ScerIO/packages.flutter/issues/397